# Rectangle Panel Graphic relationship

Tags: vb.net

The following code does not work:

```
Private Sub panelButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles panelButton.Click

    Dim myBrush As Brush
    myBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Yellow)

    fBitmap = New Bitmap(picturePanel.Width, picturePanel.Height)
    Dim gg As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(fBitmap)
    gg.Clear(Color.White)

    '<<<<<my attempt<<<<<<
    Dim rec As Rectangle
    rec = New Rectangle(picturePanel.Location.X, picturePanel.Location.Y, picturePanel.Width, picturePanel.Height)
    gg.FillRectangle(myBrush, rec)
    '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 

    'gg.FillRectangle(myBrush, gg.ClipBounds) '<<actual answer

    gg.Dispose()
    picturePanel.Refresh()
End Sub
```

In the Panel's repaint handler I've got this:

```
Private Sub picturePanel_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles picturePanel.Paint
    If fBitmap IsNot Nothing Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(fBitmap, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

I've included the recommended code (marked as `actual answer`) but why doesn't the section marked `my attempt` turn the panel yellow? - can it be tweaked so that it turns the panel yellow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rec = New Rectangle(picturePanel.Location.X, picturePanel.Location.Y, _
                    picturePanel.Width, picturePanel.Height)
```

That's the wrong rectangle.  It is relative from the panel's Parent instead of the panel itself.  At best you'll see the rectangle at the far right-bottom corner.  Or not at all if it is off the bitmap.  Draw relative to the bitmap's upper left corner instead.  Fix:

```
rec = New Rectangle(0, 0, fBitmap.Width, fBitmap.Height)
```

Do note that you'll no longer see any white since you completely overdrew that.  It isn't clear what you meant to do.  Perhaps more illustrative is to give it a yellow border:

```
rec = New Rectangle(0, 0, fBitmap.Width-1, fBitmap.Height-1)
gg.DrawRectangle(Pens.Yellow, rec)
```

Do favor the Using statement instead of the explicit Dispose() call.  Also use it on the brush, it should be disposed as well.